# SRE-Docker Compose for CRON job

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron, dockerfile

We had a task to Create a docker file with ubuntu image

1. Create a print.sh file which has code to print date and time
2. Write a cron file named "hello-cron" which includes the print.sh to
   run for every 1 min.
3. The docker image should have a CRON job to print date and time every
   1 min

We created a print.sh file via vi command and in it given as

```
#!/bin/sh -l
time=$(date)
echo "::set-output name=time::$time"
```

After which we had executed -

```
chmod +x print.sh
```

then tried as -

```
* * * * * /home/scrapbook/tutorial
```

Getting error as -

```
$ * * * * * /home/scrapbook/tutorial
bash: print.sh: command not found
```

Not sure where we went wrong, please guide us.

Comment: please help us or suggest us please

Answer (score 1):

Give full path in the cronjob like * * * * * /[fullpath]/print.sh